# iPod UISlider images for retina display - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

I want to make my default UISlider like iPod UISlider (volume or tracking), but I can't find UISlider images for Retina display. I found only [this](http://img200.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=whiteslide.png). But this is not for Retina display. Where I can find this images?

Comment: Arn't these the default images?, What exactly do you want? Do you wan't different images?, And can't you use the default UISlider? You need to be clearer in your question if you want an appropriate answer.

Comment: I need to make UISlider like in iPod application. Default UISlider looks another. And no, these images aren't default. I need same images but for Retina display

Comment: If they arn't the default images, then you would have to create them yourself, (or pay someone to do it for you). There are possibly places online. You could use this to extract the default images, and then edit those https://github.com/davepeck/iphone-tidbits/tree/master/iOS-artwork

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on your hard disk you can find the app "Springboard.app". on my installation it is here:

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/

if you open it via right click and "Show Package Contents", you will find apple's artwork. if you can't find the knob inside (didn't check), it is probably drawn directly viv core graphics.

**Note**: I have no idea, if you can use this legally

**edit**
Maybe I misunderstood your question.

If you are targeting only iOS 5, I strongly recommend watching **[Session 114 - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=114)**<sub>developer login required</sub> of the *WWDC 2011 Session Videos*. It show how to change iOS controls appearance app-wide.

Comment: I will try It at home, thank you.
You understood my question correctly. I've seen here, on stackoverflow one app that allows to get all iOS SDK recources. Now I can't find it:(